# primitive polynomial and irreducible

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Prove that every [irreducible polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) over $\mathbb{Z}$ must be [primitive](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePolynomial.html).

I have tried proving this contraction by taking a [polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polynomial.html), f(x) to not be primitive. Let p be the content of the polynomial. I have reduced the polynomial by [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) p. But I am not sure how to arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem only holds if $\deg f>0$.

Suppose $f$ is not primitive and has degree $>0$. Then $f(x) = p g(x)$ for some prime $p$ and $\deg g>0$, so $g$ is not a unit. But this is a reduction as $p$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. So not primitive implies not irreducible.

Contrapositive gives desired result.

For a counterexample when $\deg f= 0$, consider $f= p$ a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $f$ is not primitive but is irreducible.

Convince yourself the following proposition actually holds: $f$ is irreducible implies either $f$ primitive or $f = p \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is an irreducible element of $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. a prime since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD).

Note that irreducibles are non-units by definition.

Comment: How can we know that g(x) is not a unit?

Comment: Made some edits. There are some some-what trivial edge cases to deal with.